SSIS - Run a query for multiple servers and insert the results in a table from a different server - using Script Component and OLE DB Destination
I am trying to run a query for multiple servers, but it is not inserting the results into the destination table from a different server. By debugging the Script from script component I got the error: Invalid Object Name: 'the table I am using to insert the results'. It works when running the query for the server where the destination table is, but not when running on a different server.
In OLE DB Destination, I select the name of the destination table from drop list and it brings the schema next to the name; so the table is found.
Am I missing something?
I only tried using OLE DB Destination. Is is correct or should I use another component?

Please show code and a repeatable examle:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I just found the error;  inside the query that is running on different servers is used destination table for left join without the server in the name. Thank you for your support!
